# SQLAlchemy Autoflush does not work on Session.add

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to save new objects in DB and receive autoincrement ID of new entity without call `session.flush()`. I tried `autoflush=True` [(docs)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.params.autoflush) option but had no luck.

Here my code.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, as_declarative

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:@localhost/postgres")
Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine)
session = Session()
print(session.autoflush)  # -> True

@as_declarative()
class Base:
    __name__: str

class UserDb(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username: str = Column(String, unique=True)
    hashed_password: str = Column(String)
    is_active: bool = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    is_superuser: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False)


user = UserDb(
    username="username",
    hashed_password="password",
)
session.add(user)
# Here I want to have user.id
print(user.id)  # -> None
session.flush()
print(user.id)  # -> 12
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior in SQLAlchemy?

Env: `python 3.9.7`, `SQLAlchemy 1.4.27`

Comment: Quoting the docs you cited: "When [autoflush is] `True`, all query operations will issue a `Session.flush()` call to this `Session` **before** proceeding." (Emphasis mine.) So the `session.add()` will not be flushed until the next "query operation" happens on the Session. And you need the flush to get the autoincrement ID value from the server. That's just how it works.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, I understand that `autoflush` can't solve my problem. But I cannot get why SQLAlchemy was designed in this way. It's inconvenient to call flush after every add. I'm new to SQLAlchemy usually use DjangoORM so maybe I don't understand something.

Comment: Why do you need the actual ID value? You already have the object in the session (identity map) so you can just continue to work with it until such time as you want to commit.

Comment: One thing that might trip new users is that you do not need to know the ID to make relationships between entities. You can leave that to SQLA, if using the [relationships API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html).

Comment: @IljaEverilä - Yeah, that what I was hinting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure, that it's an anti-pattern, but I've achieved desired behavior with monkey patching SQLAlchemy

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


def add_decorator(method):  # type: ignore
    """
    Flush session to Database for Create/Update queries
    Useful for instant retrieving Autoincrement IDs

    So instead
    session.add(obj)
    session.flush()

    We can write just
    session.add(obj)

    But this solution requires more DB calls.
    To optimize code with large amount of session.add calls use

    with session.no_autoflush:
        ...
    """

    def wrapper(self, instance, _warn=True):  # type: ignore
        method(self, instance, _warn)
        if self.autoflush:
            self.flush()

    return wrapper


def patch() -> None:
    Session.add = add_decorator(Session.add)  # type: ignore
```

Then you call `patch()` wherever you need to turn on `autoflush`